# Office Add-in disappearing from ribbon while still being installed

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, office-js

### Issue

I've had users reporting that the button for reaching our task-pane Office Add-in (on the ribbon) disappears. There are cases where multiple add-ins are enabled, but ours is the only one that is missing. Seems like it is occurring on both Mac and Windows.

When they look in the Store it still looks like it is enabled. One way to fix it is to remove the add-in and install it again, but when it happens reguraly it's annoying and users can't bother to fix it every time.

- The add-in is hosted on S3 in AWS
- The add-in is configured to only be visible when composing email

### Question

What could be the cause of this happening? How can we fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no known issues surrounding this. Where the Add-in is hosted, should not matter. If where your icon is cannot be reached, then your add-in will load after a certain amount of time with a default icon. (this does not sound like what is happening, but this can cause your add-in to not show up for a while)

In general, when users complain about this, it is because they have switched tabs on the ribbon. This can be confusing because add-ins are in a different location when doing an inline reply vs doing a pop-out window. (see below screenshot). Most of the time, this occurs during inline reply, and the user has clicked away from the "message" ribbon to the "Home" ribbon. Clicking back on the "message" ribbon, and the add-in should show up again. If the "message" ribbon is not there, then selecting another message, then back on the draft should put the "message" ribbon back.

[image]
Another possible explanation is that an admin has disabled the add-in, but not installed it.

If this is not what is happening, we would need more information on the repro steps. Version numbers of the Client Hosts. Version number of the server, and perhaps a copy of the add-in manifest.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me a lot to consider. I'll forward this to my users.